# Have different content in storyboard between target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm adding new project target for making new app on my Xcode project which is used storyboard. It will have exactly same function, only differences are things related on name e.g bundle name, app icon etc.

I just did add a new target from project setting and did some configurations and things gonna be fine. But I have a problem.

There are UILabels presenting product name e.g. "My Apps" in Login scene storyboard file. I want change UILabel.text depend on target.

What I've done about this matter is I connected IBOutlet to UIViewController class and implemented to change UILabel's text in viewDidLoad method. It works properly.

But, I'm wondering there is better way to fix this issue. Actually I tried to use localisation but I didn't find out.

Could you give me an any idea about this matter?

Thanks.

Comment: that means you need to localize that label text?

Comment: @DipenChudasama No, localisation depends on Languages, what I want is something depends on Target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly you could use a pList in order to define all of your names and titles and inside of your code reference the pList parameter to set your UILabel.text, etc.

Then, you can simply define a pList for each target and all you will need to change is which pList to use depending on the target and set your UILabels and other text to the value of the pList key.

Comment: Yes, that is similar what I did, and it's better idea to use plist file. Thank you.

Comment: Is this solution practical for a large number of strings ?